# General Interface Syntax : using variable names

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax, interface

In languages like Java and c#, when you declare an interface the parameters on the functions have variable names. Could you make it more minimal and have the syntax work like this:

```
void Print( String );
```

Instead of the current

```
void Print( String str );
```

Other then readability, where the variables help define what the parameters are supposed to be, are there reasons require variable names on interfaces?

Readability example:

```
void doSomething( long, long );
```

versus

```
void doSomething( long id, long timeLimitMilli );
```

Comment: I think your analysis is spot-on, it's just about readability. In plain old C header files, the names are ignored, and can be different from the implemenation that appears later, and can in fact be omitted just like you show in doSomething.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test I would say the answer is "not a bit":

./a/Foo.java

```
public interface Foo {
    void run(int x);
}
```

./b/Foo.java

```
public interface Foo {
    void run(int y);
}
```

Then

```
$ sha1sum ./a/Foo.class
7ae75c91f553e09e5a06d5630134e63d650d734e  ./a/Foo.class
$ sha1sum ./b/Foo.class
7ae75c91f553e09e5a06d5630134e63d650d734e  ./b/Foo.class
```

ie Java cares so little about the parameter names they are discarded entirely on compiling. They are, for all intents and purposes, comments.

Comment: Makes sense, but then why are we forced to have variable names on interfaces if that's they're not kept.

Comment: Well you can Javadoc `@param` them I guess.

Comment: @jex - You answered it yourself -- readability, even in the absence of Javadoc. In addition, those variable names are used automatically in generated code implementing the interface.